# Django Form Post

Tags: python, django

Im trying to get POST method working in Python DJango. But couldn't succeed with CSRF implementation.

Here is what I in my Views.py

```
def showTime(request):      
    t = get_template('FR/current_datetime.html')
    htmlContent = t.render(Context({"day_list": ['wednesday','thursday','friday'] , "current_date": datetime.datetime.now()} ))
    return HttpResponse(htmlContent)

def showWeekEnd(request):           
   c = {}
   c.update(csrf(request))
   if request.method == 'POST':
       return render_to_response('EN/current_datetime.html', c)
```

and my URL Pattern is

```
url(r'^showTime/$', showTime),
    url(r'^$', showTime),
    url(r'^showWeekEnd/$', showWeekEnd),
```

I also enabled

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
)
```

I have (EN/current_datetime.html)

```
<form action="/showWeekEnd/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

For this I'm getting

```
TypeError: csrf() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Should I have to pass any more parameters., this error Im getting when I launch the application itself with "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator."

Please explain what went wrong?

Comment: what is this? `c = {}; c.update(csrf(request))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
#settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...,
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',)
```

In your view, use csrf decorator instead of manually adding it.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.template import RequestContext

@csrf_protect
def showWeekEnd(request):
    c = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('EN/current_datetime.html', c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add RequestContext(request) in your render_to_response ?

views.py

```
from django.template import RequestContext

return render_to_response('EN/current_datetime.html', c, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: YES I tried that too. Also I have a feel that it is not even coming to code section.

Comment: Try pass RequestContext in GET request, before POST.

Comment: One more thing I noticed., I get this error moment I enable this  "django.core.context_processors.csrf" in "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES".

Comment: "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware" should be in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, not "django.core.context_processors.csrf". Maybe you have wrong import of csrf in views.py, it should be "from django.core.context_processors import csrf"

Comment: Yes that cleared the initial issue., Thank You. I'll try to get rest of them working.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

def showWeekEnd(request):           
   if request.method == 'POST':
       return render(request, 'EN/current_datetime.html')

def showTime(request):      
    c = {}
    c["day_list"] = ['wednesday','thursday','friday']
    c["current_date"] = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'FR/current_datetime.html', c)
```

Comment: Thank you !! I noticed one this I just commented "'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'," in "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES" and tried the same code still it works. Then how the CSRF token gets processed?

Comment: @ Burhan Khalid I found the reason. If I comment django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware then no validation will be done. Thank you !!